# RoR issue because of sqlite on M1 Apple MBP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apple-m1

I will not try to be a Rails guru because I am not one and I know that. But on my new M1 chip Apple Macbook I find it hard to make Rails work properly... I installed through Homebrew whatever I was able to, and now I have the following versions of rbenv:

```
  system
  2.7.2
 * 3.0.3
```

I have the following ruby version installed: `ruby 3.0.3p157 (2021-11-24 revision 3fb7d2cadc) [arm64-darwin20]`.

Now if I want to run any rails or gem command, like `rails version` or `gem list --local`, I get the same error message all the time (also I am using 7.0.2.1  version):

```
Ignoring sqlite3-1.4.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine sqlite3 --version 1.4.2
```

Also when I check the version of the SQLite installed with homebrew I got this version: `sqlite 3.37.2`.

I also see the following message in the error: `It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output). To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.`, but libyaml is installed `libyaml 0.2.5`, and I still can't get rid of this error, no matter what I do.

I am trying for a week already and getting tired of it :/ Anyone here with better DevOps/RoR knowledge who could help me out would be a living Messiah.

Comment: and did you try the suggested `gem pristine sqlite3 --version 1.4.2`? this is the version of the gem, not of sqlite anyway

Comment: Of course, I did, sorry if I forgot to mention that.